# RStudio appears to be importing in data incorrectly. Any suggestions?

Tags: r

I'm currently using RStudio to analyze a few sets of data. When I open the data in R, I see the correct data, which should be years (see photo).

However, when I try to view the data in RStudio, the same column contains numbers ranging from 1-60.

I'm specifically looking at MobileMember$Birth in these screenshots.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed? Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Output from R]

[image: Output from RStudio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you importing the data into r? As a csv or as .txt? Try saving the excel file as a csv and importing it that way:

```
MobileMember <- read.csv(file path)
```

It sounds like R is reading the column as an integer and then ranking them based on the year. Try changing the column to a factor.

You can see how R is reading the column using the str() command

```
str(MobileMember)
```

If it is listed as an integer, change the column to a factor using:

```
MobileMember$Birth <- as.factor(MobileMember$Birth)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I was able to use read.dta to import my .dta files into RStudio.